# How to return custom thumbnail size of featured image in Pods

Tags: php, wordpress, podscms

I've registered several custom thumbnail sizes for a site I've been given control over, and want to be able to call on them in the template code, which is set up like this

```
 <img id="product_thumb" class="border--round" alt="Image" src="<?php echo $vehiclepods->field('featured_image')['guid']; ?>">
```

Where do I pass the thumbnail parameter, or even force a size?

[Sample template here](https://pastebin.com/S6YQCEgv)

[Functions here](https://pastebin.com/PBa45YbJ)

Answer (score 1):

Found the missing bit between the field and the thumbnail.

```
featured_image._src.speedmaster_front
```

Answer (score -1):

Depending on your settings and pod configuration

```
$vehiclepods->field('featured_image.speedmaster_front')
```

should output the Full Image!

More details about how to get just the link or more in the Pods Documentation:

[field()](https://pods.io/docs/code/pods/field/)

[display()](https://pods.io/docs/code/pods/display/)

[Magic Tags](https://pods.io/docs/build/using-magic-tags/)

Comment: Hmm, afraid that isn't working, no matter which thumbnail size I put in there. Will keep plugging at it.